# Can't find any device while scanning for bluetooth device using esc_pos_printer: ^2.1.2 package in flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

I was trying to connect flutter with bluetooth thermal_printer using esc_pos_printer: ^2.1.2 package.

> D/BluetoothBasicPlugin(18555): start scan  D/BluetoothAdapter(18555):
> STATE_ON D/BluetoothLeScanner(18555): onClientRegistered() - status=0
> clientIf=6 D/BluetoothAdapter(18555): STATE_ON
> D/BluetoothBasicPlugin(18555): start scan  D/BluetoothAdapter(18555):
> STATE_ON D/BluetoothLeScanner(18555): onClientRegistered() - status=0
> clientIf=6 D/BluetoothAdapter(18555): STATE_ON
> D/BluetoothBasicPlugin(18555): start scan  D/BluetoothAdapter(18555):
> STATE_ON D/BluetoothLeScanner(18555): onClientRegistered() - status=0
> clientIf=6 D/BluetoothAdapter(18555): STATE_ON

repeat these lines when scanning
my code is given below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:esc_pos_printer/esc_pos_printer.dart';
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  PrinterBluetoothManager printerManager = PrinterBluetoothManager();

  List<PrinterBluetooth> _devices = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Printer Demo'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context,position)=>ListTile(
          onTap: (){
            //code to print with this device
            printerManager.selectPrinter(_devices[position]);
            Ticket ticket=Ticket(PaperSize.mm58);
            ticket.text('Demo text');
            ticket.feed(1);
            ticket.cut();
            printerManager.printTicket(ticket).then((result) {
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(result.msg)));
            }).catchError((error){
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.toString())));
            });
          },
          title: Text(_devices[position].name),
          subtitle: Text(_devices[position].address),
        ),
        itemCount: _devices.length,
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
        //Code to search for devices
        printerManager.startScan(Duration(seconds: 4));
        printerManager.scanResults.listen((scannedDevices) {
          setState(() {
            _devices=scannedDevices;
          });
        });
      },child: Icon(Icons.search),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your thermal_printer a Bluetooth Classic or a Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) printer? You are using a BLE library, maybe you need to use one for Bluetooth Classic

Comment: It worked when I changed my printer. But now it print only once .when I repeat printing it does not work. Then I have to reconnect the printer and have to rerun the whole process.Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you using the same code?